# Blender 4.0 Empty Hair Curve Only adding to specific line on mesh

Tags: hair

I'm using the new Blender empty hair curve to add hair to my model.

I followed the tutorial How to Easily Create Realistic Hair using the New Hair tools in Blender by PixelicaCG,but when I go into sculpt mode to add hair to the mesh it only will add on to a single line to the head and not the full thing.

I attached two images of the issue if I need to provide more let me know, I'm pretty stumped on this.

[Full image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2bkT.png)

[image: Model with empty hair in edit mode to show the line as mentioned.]

---

Here is the second Image. Let me know if I need to provide more. [image]